# Shouldn't you be able to close your own posts right away?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The owner doesn’t have to “vote” to delete, so why vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/the-owner-doesnt-have-to-vote-to-delete-so-why-vote-to-close)

Right now, if you want to close your own question, then if your question is active you just leave a comment saying you want it closed and make a close vote yourself. (Or flag for moderator attention)

It seems more intuitive though if you can close your own questions right away? Sorta like how a diamond mod can. I just think it's pretty dumb that you can delete your own question very quickly but not close it.

Answer (score 1):

Closing is a way to delete a question while giving it a chance to be brought back if the closers misunderstood it or the author revises the question.

If you are the author, you know the intent of the question and are not misunderstanding it, and are probably not going to revise it after you closed it. Therefore there is no point to letting an author instantly close their question. (Besides UI consistency)

Bottom Line: If you think you should close your own question, it should probably just be deleted.

Comment: (Partially because in 2 days, that is what is going to happen to it anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You get the ability to vote to close your own questions at only 250 rep, and then at 3k you can do it on other people's questions.

I think it makes sense to be able to cast a binding close vote on your own questions at 3k, which is the point at which you are supposed to know when a question should be closed. For example, if you discover that your question is a dupe of another, I think it's reasonable to be able to close as a dupe immediately.

However, the truth is that this happens so infrequently I'm not sure it's worth adding extra complexity to the system. Simply flag for moderator attention and they'll take care of it. I've done this on a number of occasions and it's worked out fine that way.