# Since I have enough reputation to cast close votes, shouldn't I be able to close my own questions without waiting for other people to vote?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, vote-to-close

Example question [MySQL: Get the difference between timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764291/mysql-get-the-difference-between-timestamps)

Another user found a duplicate and did not vote to close, I voted to close... but it is not yet closed.

Maybe when closing your own question you should have more voting power or just be able to close without waiting for a vote.

Comment: See: [Allow question askers to close their own questions unilaterally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally) and [The owner doesn't have to “vote” to delete, so why vote to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/the-owner-doesnt-have-to-vote-to-delete-so-why-vote-to-close)

Answer (score 1):

The ability to close a question is given to the community.  You can delete it if there are no upvoted answers, but you aren't allowed to single-handedly close it.  In most cases, closing is one step towards deletion.

If you need to close something quickly in the future, post a message here on meta, or flag it for moderator attention, but be prepared to explain why it should be closed rather than deleted.